# Can bedbugs transmit the COVID-19 virus from person to person?

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, coronavirus, insect-bites

I am in Montreal now and unable to leave because if I go home they will sent me in quarantine in various places where I do not want to go.

**Question**: Do bedbugs transmit COVID-19 from person to person?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Comment: Calling the virus a Chinese virus is only permitted by POTUS as he knows no better.

Answer (score 2):

Bed bugs eat blood.  Red cells do not contain DNA which can be hijacked by the SARS-CoV-2 virus so the bugs should not have any viable virus unless the bug is covered with infected droplets of someone's cough.  That seems highly improbable.

> Bed bugs are not known to spread disease. Bed bugs can be an annoyance because their presence may cause itching and loss of sleep. Sometimes the itching can lead to excessive scratching that can sometimes increase the chance of a secondary skin infection.

and

> A common concern with bed bugs is whether or not they transmit diseases. Although bed bugs can harbor various pathogens, transmission to humans has not been proven and is considered unlikely.

However, blood also contains some macrophages which have been shown to possess ACE2 receptors which could lead to the macrophages getting infected though surface expression is low.  One would have to posit that the virus enters the bug's gut but somehow leaves again, and somehow reaches the bugs' beak while being unable to replicate.

To further put this into perspective a cc of blood has usually less than 15,000 white cells. The volume of blood suckled by a bed bug is a way lot less, and macrophages are further sparse in white cells at 5%.

https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.01.26.919985v1.full

https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef636

https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/bedbugs/faqs.html

Comment: DNA is present in white blood cells of humans, but not red blood cells which lack nuclei." (http://www.biology.arizona.edu/human_bio/problem_sets/DNA_forensics_2/06t.html). It appears that bedbugs, feeding with blood, also draw white cells which contain DNA and possible the coronavirus?!

Comment: Oh, well that's not good then.  I guess we'll wait and see if bed bugs get an upset tummy and whether they also become a vector.  I guess the same worry applies to mozzies and other blood sucking insects.

Comment: Doesn't it seem like if someone is in close enough contact with a space used by someone infected to meet their same bed bugs, the bed bugs are the least of their worries?

Comment: If the room has been cleaned then soap destroys the virus, and there shouldn't be any in the air as droplets fall to the ground. Hotels have air con to do frequent room air exchanges and that should remove any virus in the air from toilet flushing aerosols.

Comment: The ventilation in buildings can spread the Covid-19 as long as when one of my close neighbors (they are smokers) starts the fan in the ceiling of his toilet, and keeps it running like 15 minutes, I can feel cigarette smoke in my room. The virus can also follow the same path as the smoke and can come from any other neighbor, from people who are not smokers.

Comment: That's a pretty crappy (pun intended) ventilation system you got there!

Comment: You are nervos Graham Chiu.